# Equating Euler's Totient Function to the number of visible lattice points.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

The function $V(a)$ checks for [lattice point visibility](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VisiblePoint.html) on the line $x+y=n$ from the origin:

\begin{gather}
V(a) = 
\begin{cases}
    1& \text{if }\mathrm{gcd}(a, n-a) = 1\\
    0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{gather}

Observe that Euler's Totient Function equals the number of visible lattice points

\begin{gather}
\varphi(n) = 2 \sum_{a=1}^{\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \rfloor} V(a)
\end{gather}

**Example**

Consider the line $x+y=9$ with focus on these $3$ visible points

$\left(1,8\right),\left(2,7\right),\left(4,5\right)$

Notice due to the symmetry of the lattice points in the first quadrant with respect to the line $y=x$, we can multiply by $2$, so

$\varphi(9) = 6$

[image]

**Question**

Is this a correct formula

\begin{gather}
\varphi(n) = 2 \sum_{a=1}^{\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \rfloor} V(a)
\end{gather}

to equate the totient function $\varphi(n)$ to lattice point visibility?

Comment: Since $\,\gcd(a,n-a) = \gcd(a,n)\,$ it is just a slight rephrasing of the definition of $\,\phi(n).\,$ What do you mean by "performance"?

Comment: But the same reflection symmetry applies to the usual definition, by $\,\gcd(n-a,n) = \gcd(a,n)\ \ $