# The Euler Totient function $\varphi(n)$ approximates $\frac{6n}{\pi^2}$ on average.

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Let $V_n$ equal the number of [visible points](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VisiblePoint.html) on the line $x + y = n$.

Given the [Probability that two random numbers are coprime is $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64498/probability-that-two-random-numbers-are-coprime-is-frac6-pi2), we can state:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[V_n] \approx \frac{6n}{\pi^2}
\end{equation}

where $\mathbb{E}$ denotes the average value.

Next, [Equating Euler's Totient Function to the number of visible lattice points.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4776220/equating-eulers-totient-function-to-the-number-of-visible-lattice-points), we have

\begin{equation}
\varphi(n) = V_n
\end{equation}

and substituting gives

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[\varphi(n)] \approx \frac{6n}{\pi^2}
\end{equation}

**Question**

Is it accurate to say the equation

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[\varphi(n)] \approx \frac{6n}{\pi^2}
\end{equation}

indicates that, on average, the Euler Totient function $\varphi(n)$ approximates $\frac{6n}{\pi^2}$?

Comment: Yes, see [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7039/typical-value-of-totient-function) for more details.